# Why would Kubelet say a file exists during mounting when it doesn't?

Tags: kubernetes

I have modified the Kubernetes hostpath CSI driver to use the https://github.com/mesosphere/csilvm driver.  My deployment creates the LV for the PVC but fails to mount it into the pod with this description:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                    From            Message
  ----     ------       ----                   ----            -------
  Warning  FailedMount  23m (x1127 over 8d)    kubelet, node2  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[clvm-volume], unattached volumes=[default-token-bzfcz clvm-volume]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  9m6s (x6021 over 8d)   kubelet, node2  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-3df13ff4-0342-4522-a70d-f424dd6c6d5f" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Cannot create mount target /var/lib/kubelet/pods/901a8f98-7162-4168-a822-5c973bd0e6dc/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-3df13ff4-0342-4522-a70d-f424dd6c6d5f/mount: err=mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods/901a8f98-7162-4168-a822-5c973bd0e6dc/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-3df13ff4-0342-4522-a70d-f424dd6c6d5f/mount: file exists
  Warning  FailedMount  3m12s (x4278 over 8d)  kubelet, node2  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[clvm-volume], unattached volumes=[clvm-volume default-token-bzfcz]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

I think this is telling me kubelet issued a mount and it failed because there is a file with that name already at the mount point.  When I go on to the node I see nothing in the the directly specified.

```
[root@node2 kubernetes.io~csi]# pwd
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/901a8f98-7162-4168-a822-5c973bd0e6dc/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi
[root@node2 kubernetes.io~csi]# ls -lta
total 0
drwxr-x---. 2 root root  6 Jul 30 10:06 .
drwxr-x---. 4 root root 59 Jul 22 20:25 ..
[root@node2 kubernetes.io~csi]#
```

I'm confused on how I could get kubelet confused.

Comment: [a relevant issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/1128) happened due to a stale file handle; is the behavior you're experiencing reproducible, and does it happen on every Node?

Comment: I found the issue.  It was in the csi driver not expecting the CO to create the directory.

Comment: Please do consider add that as an answer, linking to the issue, writing what steps you took to resolve it, then accepting your answer; it'll help others find your solution

Comment: How did you fix it? I have the same issue when trying to mount a Postgres's script to minikube. The kubelet says "Error: failed to start container "postgres": Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/home/docker/postgres-scripts': mkdir /home/docker/postgres-scripts: file exists". I expect kubelet shouldn't say that because it was the first time I had deployed the postgres in minikube's k8s. The directory couldn't exist before that.